# Adding GeoEye1 sensor to grass i.atcorr

Tags: grass-gis, remote-sensing, compilation

Following the instructions, I've updated the iwave.h and iwave.cpp files using the official spectral responses from DigitalGlobe (In the iwave.h file I don't know if it's necessary to use more accurate wavelength ranges). Now I don't know how (and I don't have much time!) to go on the next steps.. (update geomcond files and recompile grass), I have never compiled a software!! :)
Could someone help me? I can send you all the updated files, of course..

Comment: Great news! Just a hint - compile instructions you can find here: http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Compile_and_Install

Answer (score 1):

Great! More improvements! If you are determined to see this through you can :

1. Subscribe yourself at [grass-dev mailing list](http://lists.osgeo.org/listinfo/grass-dev)
2. Sent an email to the list making known your intentions.
3. Ask if anyone's willing to proof read it/fix bugs.
4. Follow any instructions.